# Question on combinatorics and the inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

Find the number of n digit-numbers formed using the first 5 natural numbers, that contain the digits '2' and '4', essentially.

I tried attempting this with the inclusion- exclusion principle but got stuck with the first 5 natural numbers condition. I made 2 sets, one with natural numbers where 2 is there and another with numbers with 5 is there and tried to find their intersection, but got stuck while subtracting from the total set, ie, the set of natural n digit numbers that are made from the digits 1 to 5 (wo any restrictions)
hence i have a doubt in how to find the total number of elements in the set of n digit numbers that are made from the first 5 natural numbers.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you show your work to explain how/why you got stuck?

Comment: yeah i tried to use the principle such that i made 2 sets, one with natural numbers where 2 is there and another with numbers with 5 is there and tried to find their intersection, but when i was subtracting the thing i got stuck with what to subtract from since i cant figure out how to form the numbers (without any restrictions, ie i cant figure out how to find the set which contains all the natural numbers that are n digit and made from the first 5 digits.)

Comment: Can you add those details into the post? In particular, how you're using PIE. The words that you've written doesn't quite make sense to me as yet.

Comment: Right, i will, sorry

Comment: so basically i have a doubt in how to find the total set of n digit numbers made with the digits 1 to 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total number of $n$-digit numbers formed from $12345$ is $5^n$. The count of those numbers not containing a $2$ or $4$ is $4^n$ each, and the count of those not containing either is $3^n$. Thus the required answer is $5^n-2\cdot4^n+3^n$.

Comment: ah i see, so each digit has basically 5 options, so the total digits is 5^n , and then u do the same for the others, and when u add and subtract accordingly, u get the required answer. Thanks a lot!